# Open Applescript Application from Safari Bookmark

Tags: safari, applescript, bookmarks

I was wondering if it was possible to open an Applescript application from a bookmark on Safari.

The applescript opens a new tab, with a url, and types in some keystrokes, and I have the app on my Desktop.

Possibly the "Open File" or file:/// thingy.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. You could create your own file type handler app to launch an applescript from a URL, and you can google folks offering how to do that. But in a vanilla install, no, you can not.
You should consider putting the script in the Script Menu. This will accomplish the same thing, namely, having a menu item that will launch your script.